# Firebase Security Open Access

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My android wallpaper app is connected to `Firebase Cloud Firestore`. It doesn't have any user authentication because I want the user to be able to use it without fuss. To do this, it must be in open access, meaning, the user is allowed to `read` and `write`. This is dangerous as he can also edit and modify the data if he knows the project id. The project id is visible in the url of the app so this is not really a good choice. Closed access is also not an option for obvious reasons.

Is there anything I can do to protect my data without need of a user authentication? I would love to see the code needed for the Cloud Firestore and Storage to protect the data. I want the user to read only and I, as the owner, should be the only one who could write. Please refer to the images attached. Thanks a lot for taking time to answer my questions.

**My data structure in Firebase Cloud Firestore:**
[image: Screenshot of the data structure]

Comment: Please check this out. I might have interpreted it differently. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/insecure-rules

Comment: I posted an answer to your question. If you clarify your question and add some details (especially on your `Firebase Cloud Firestore` data structure and what a user should be allowed to do) I can update my answer with a specific set of security rules.

Comment: I would love to see the security rules. My Firebase Cloud Firestore has categories and documents. The user is allowed to download as well as share on social media the images. Thank you.

Comment: I can only help you with the security rules if you show the exact hierarchies and structure of your data in `Firebase Cloud Firestore`. It’s also important to know what access a user should have to each path. In the meantime take a look at my answer below and accept/upvote it if it answers your question.

Comment: I have accepted the answer. I'm sorry I didn't know I could do that. How do I attach images to show you the structure of my data?

Comment: I would suggest that you edit your initial question by clicking on "edit" below the body and tags of your question. There you can add easily upload images to your question. You have to save your edit at the bottom of the page. Please also give some information about what access rights there should be in specific and if you have built in some authentication mechanism as described in my answer (e.g. anonymous auth).

Comment: I checked your data structure and updated my question with two different sets of security rules. Choose the option that fits your needs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Securing your data with Security Rules

`Firebase Cloud Firestore`, `Firebase Realtime Database` and `Firebase Cloud Storage` are secured by their own Security Rules. They provide access control and data validation in a simple yet expressive format and allow you to control access to documents and collections in your database.

*To build user-based and role-based access systems that keep your users' data safe, you need to use `Firebase Authentication` with Cloud Firestore Security Rules.*

#### Your specific use case

I assume that you store your data in `Firebase Cloud Firestore` and the wallpapers in `Firebase Cloud Storage`. The user then gets a document with a link to download a wallpaper and maybe also can upload their own wallpapers to the database.

#### The dangers of an open database

As you mentioned allowing all reads and writes to your database in a production app is very dangerous. Obviously, anyone with your database reference will be able to read or write data to your database. Unauthorized users could destroy your backend and there are also possibilities that costs could increase exponentially. Therefore this is not recommended. There always should be some mechanisms preventing these scenarios.

#### Recommendation: Using anonymous authentication first and connect later with existing Identity Providers

I recommend that you use `Firebase Authentication` [to create and use temporary anonymous accounts to authenticate with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth?hl=en). These temporary anonymous accounts can be used to allow users who haven't yet signed up to your app to work with data protected by security rules while not being in the way of your user experience. If an anonymous user later decides to sign up to your app, you can link their sign-in credentials to the anonymous account so that they can continue to work with their protected data in future sessions.

You could also enable Google-Sign-In, Facebook Login, Twitter, GitHub, Microsoft, Yahoo, etc. to let users authenticate in a very fast and easy way without compromising on a security standpoint if using regular password authentication is not what you want (from a UX standpoint). `FirebaseUI` makes it really easy to add these to your existing app. Check out the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui?hl=en) on this topic.

#### Implementing Cloud Firestore Security Rules

The [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started?hl=en) on this is really great on how to get started with Cloud Firestore Security Rules.

**However these security rules could work for you:**

Allow read access to all users to the root (Not recommended because this can create huge costs in production). Users don't have write (create, update, delete) access. In this case you can edit your data via the Firebase Console. Choose either option 1 or option 2 for your project.

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
    // Option 1: Matches any document in the 'root' collection.
    match /root/{rumiXYZ} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false;
    }

    // Option 2: Matches any document in the 'root' collection or subcollections.
    match /root/{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

The `{document=**}` path in the rules above can be used to match any document in the collection/subcollections or in the entire database. This should however not be necessary for your use case. Continue on to the guide for [structuring security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure) to learn how to match specific data paths and work with hierarchical data.

**Don't forget to secure your Firebase Cloud Storage too!**